# optimized bit manipulation for getting the NOT value

Tags: c++, c, optimization, bit-manipulation

I have a unsigned 16 bit number,a  ,and I need to get the value for ~a. Simply taking the value of ~a does not work( for a=10, I need ~a=5, not ~a=7FF5).
The best I could come up with is:

```
int negate(int a)
{
 int mask1 = 0x4000;
 int mask2 = 0x7FFF;

 for (int i=0;i<15;i++)
 {
   if (!(a&mask1))
   {
      mask1>>=1;
      mask2>>=1;
   }
   else
      break;   
 }

 int t = (0x7FFF - ~a) & mask2;

 return t;    
}
```

The problem with this is that it's too slow; do you know of a faster way to get the result I need?

Thanks for your help

Comment: So only the significant bits count?

Comment: And for `a=5`, you would want `2` as a result?

Comment: What makes you think that ~10 should be 5?

Comment: What you want as result when a is 32768?

Comment: .. or any value over?

Comment: ~5 surely is not 10, unless you're talking nibbles. But 10 must be equal to ~~10. Thus ~10 cannot be 5. So... what are those numbers, surely not `int`?

Comment: Find the Next Power of 2 for the input, then XOR with this value minus 1?

Comment: Just to verify: what you want is to invert all the bits up to and including the most significant bit of the input that's set, but leave all the bits higher than that as zero's?

Comment: 10 in binary is 1010 so I'm looking to for the number which has those bits flipped 0101 (5).

Comment: I am dealing with 16 bit unsigned numbers, you choose a different data type (I chose int) but the data type here is not important - you know the numbers will be 0<=a<2^15

Comment: @Pandrei int is 4 bytes long not just 2 bytes

Comment: @niko the data type is not important as long as it's large enough. If I would have used uint16_t in my example I would have had the same problem.

Comment: @Jongware that would work; there are a few cases for which this solution would take longer, but most of the time I think it's better

Comment: @MrLister for a=5 (0101b), I would expect ~a=10 (1010b)

Comment: @Jongware please convert your comment into an answer

Comment: Um, no, as your last comment indicates it is *not* what you are looking fo here. I'm at a loss to what is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Just to verify: what you want is to invert all the bits up to and including the most significant bit of the input that's set, but leave all the bits higher than that as zero's?

If that is indeed the case, then here is the code for that:

```
// inspired by Hacker's Delight
unsigned significant_bits(unsigned x)
{
    x |= (x >>  1);
    x |= (x >>  2);
    x |= (x >>  4);
    x |= (x >>  8);
    // x |= (x >> 16); // only needed for 32-bit integers
    return x;
}

unsigned negate(unsigned x)
{
    return x ^ significant_bits(x);
}
```

Comment: I know 0<=a<2^15 and I want to get the number which has only the useful bits flipped(e.g a=3, ~a=0, a=0x1100, ~a = 0x0EFF;  etc...

Comment: if you call hibit(10), after the first 4 lines x=0x0f; So I'm not sure what it's supposed to do, but it does not look right.

Comment: Good interpretation of the question and nice answer

Comment: @Pandrei You are supposed to call `negate`, not `hibit`.

Comment: @Pandrei If this is what you wanted, then why did you say you wanted negate(5) to be 10, above? With this solution, negate(5) will come out 2.

Comment: @Pandrei I simplified the code quite a bit (no pun intended), see the update.

Comment: Also: unsigned negate(unsigned x) { return x ^ significant_bits(x); }  which should turn into fewer instructions.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want `~a & 0xF`.

Comment: Just realised I may have misunderstood -- is `a` always less than 16?

Comment: Please read my question again, the numbers are 16 bit unsigned.

Comment: @Pandrei From your comments (~1010 binary should be 0101 and ~0101 should be 1010) it's VERY CLEAR that it's about 4 bits numbers, not 16 bits. If you implement Jongware's solution, ~0101 will not result in 1010!

Answer (score 2):

```
 int negate(unsigned int a) {

   if(a==0);
   else if(a==1) a = 0; 
   else if(a<4) a ^= 0x0003;
   else if(a<8) a ^= 0x0007;
   else if(a<16) a ^= 0x000f;
   else if(a<32) a ^= 0x001f;
   else if(a<64) a ^= 0x003f;
   else if(a<128) a ^= 0x007f;
   else if(a<256) a ^= 0x00ff;
   else if(a<512) a ^= 0x01ff;
   else if(a<1024) a ^= 0x03ff;
   else if(a<2048) a ^= 0x07ff;
   else if(a<4096) a^= 0x0fff;
   else if(a<8192) a ^= 0x1fff;
   else if(a<16384) a ^= 0x3fff;
   else if(a<32768) a ^= 0x7fff;
   else a^=0xffff; 
   return a;

 }

 int main()
{

 printf("%d",negate(10));
 return 0;
}
```

If you want to increase the size say to a 32 bit number you could just add else if branches. The first case

```
  a==0; the result is a itself
  a==1; the result is 0, simple assigning 0 is fine .
```

Or simple you could put it in a loop and take a variable say `i` just left shift by 1 each time. and then return `a ^ = (i - 1) ;`

Answer (score 1):

Pass the mask with the call to `negate()`:

```
int negate(int a, int mask)
{
    return ~a & mask;
}
```

Execution examples:

```
negate(0x000A, 0x000F) == 0x0005
negate(0x000A, 0x00F0) == 0x00F0
```

Update:

```
int negate(int num)
{
    unsigned int bitMask = 0xFFFFFFFF;

    for(unsigned int bit = 0x80000000; bit != 0; bit >>= 1)
    {
        if(bit & num)
            break;

        bitMask /= 2 ;
    }

    return ~num & bitMask;
}
```

Comment: that would work if you knew the number, you only know 0<=a<2^15

Comment: This is the same as my algorithm except yours works for 32 bit values; But I only need it for 16 bit values. But the logic is the same as what I cam up with.

Comment: @Pandrei 'Twould appear so.